# Is Roslyn Scripting Safe, or is it a code injection vulnerability?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, roslyn

We are looking to add scripting, to execute server side, in a c#/.net 4.6/aspx application.

The path we found so far is [Roslyn scripting](https://daveaglick.com/posts/compiler-platform-scripting)

- Is it safe to allow user created scripts like this to run in our process? (Where there are database connection strings and other things in process.)
- Can we cap the CPU and memory resources used by a script?

Comment: We are using `CodeDomProvider` to  create dll then import it into appdomain. But we are creating classes, interfaces and whatnot. What kind of complexity do you expect from your scripts

Comment: No it's not safe, unless you work (hard) to try to make it so. But by default it's not.

Comment: @Evk That confirms our suspicion. So what is the safe option to add user-created scripting to our app?

Comment: Most people use separate app domain with restricted permissions (usually called sandbox) to run such code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox. But if you read this link - big warning there does not recommend to do that for external untrusted code (your case). Really correct way to handle this is run it in separate virtual environment, such as docker. If that is too complicated for your case - at least run in sandbox as described, and carefully restrict permissions of user this process run by.

Comment: @Evk Thanks. Appdomains seem a non starter, because they are not a real sandbox (they are still in process, so have access to the process memory space, and appdomains cannot be limited by cpu or memory). So out of process seems the only way. Which means building a full clone of the app, minus a few things, and passing lots of large objects over the wire.  Yuck!